# How to define url/path for each style with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to have a different URL definition for each style, something like:

```
has_attached_file :asset, styles: {
                              original: "1920x1920>",
                              cropped: {:geometry => "200x200#", :processors => [:cropper] }
                            }, 
                            urls: {
                              original: "/images/:hash_path/:filename",
                              cropped: "/images/:hash_path/cropped/:filename"`
                            }
```

The goal is to store the same image only once according to the MD5 checksum (fingerprint), but use the checksum of the current style (like thumb, cropped) instead of the original file.

Example: 10 students uploaded the same school photo and selected area of their face for avatar creation. The large school photo should be saved only once in the storage, but keep each avatar is necessary.

So far I haven't found a easy way how to do it with Paperclip which is able to save fingerprint just for the original image now. I'm curious if there is a way how to define url per style? That could particularly solve this.

Thanks for any other suggestions how to proceed.

**Edit:** By `/:hash_path` I mean some kind of interpolation like mentioned here http://jonathanng.com/ruby-on-rails/getting-around-ext3-inode-limitations-using-md5-file-paths-and-paperclip-interpolations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion to proceed is to use interpolations https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations

Set url something like:

```
:url => "/attachments/:hash_path/:basename_:style.:extension",
```

then in the interpolations:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :hash_path do |attachment, style|
  hash_path = "whatever_#{style}" # generate hash path here
end
```

this should put whatever `hash_path` interpolation returns into url replacing the `:hash_path` key.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I didn't realize that style is also available in the interpolation block. So this is behaviour I wanted:

`Paperclip.interpolates :md5_path do |attachment, style|
  if style == :thumb
    "#{attachment.instance.asset_fingerprint[0..2]}/#{attachment.instance.asset_fingerprint[3..5]}/#{attachment.instance.album.token_folder}/#{attachment.instance.asset_fingerprint}"
  else
    "#{attachment.instance.asset_fingerprint[0..2]}/#{attachment.instance.asset_fingerprint[3..5]}/#{attachment.instance.asset_fingerprint}"
  end
end`